# Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream() returns null

Tags: java, windows-services, classpath

I have following code block in my application;

```
InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(FilePath);
```

Here 'FilePath' is an absolute path of the file.

Above code works fine in linux and in windows when i run the application in normal mode.(ie: in command prompt)
But this is NOT working, when I run the application as a windows service. I get input stream as 'null'.

Anyone encountered such issue before? I could not find any information regarding this other than  java classloaders . Here we use "ContextClassLoader", which is the right classloader to be used..

Any clue on this?

Comment: Show us the exact path that you use. "absolute path" sounds wrong in this context.

Comment: Here my path is like repository"+ File.separator +"resources"+ File.separator +"api_templates"+ "api.xml"; (I have set home directory in my wrapper.conf file and my application starts as a service successfully)."repository directory is a first child directory from my home directory

Comment: Are you sure the ID your app runs as when it's a Service allows read access to the file you are trying to open?  If it's running as your ID fine, but not as a Service, then in my mind the only difference would be either how it's being executed or by whom it is being executed.

Comment: When you use a class loaders, you should only give a path which is relative to a resource in the class path. If you want to use absolute paths, use FileInputStream.

Comment: @PeterLawrey/all thanks for the help..FileInputstrem works fine. Changed my code like           InputStream in = new FileInputStream(filePame);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this happens because you have "." (the current folder) on the classpath. That is a) a bad idea and b) makes your app break in odd ways.

What you need to understand is the difference between a file and a resource. A file is something outside of the classpath.

You should use `File` and `FileReader` to access them.

A resource is something on the classpath. Paths for resources always use `/` as file separator and not `File.separator`.

Another way to fix this is to add `$HOME/repository/` (Linux) or `%HOME%/repository/` to the classpath and load the resource using `"resources/api_templates/api.xml"`. for this to work, `resources` must be a folder in `$HOME/repository/`.

If you don't do this, then all files in your home directory (or whatever directory you happen to start the application in) are added as resources to the classpath.

Comment: Thanks for the detail answer. Changed to FileInputStream now it works. Changed my code like InputStream in = new FileInputStream(filePame); Understood the difference between resource and file. I was trying to read a file not the resource. thanks again